# Angular 6 / 7 / 8 ngbtypeahead returns matching and non matching records both

Tags: angular, angular-material, typeahead, rxjs-observables

I am taking records from REST API and showing it in input type as a type-ahead feature, where I have to enter at least 3 letters before giving an API call.

This is my HTML code

```
<mat-form-field>                                
    <mat-label translate>Color</mat-label>
        <input matInput #coatcolor="ngModel" name="coatcolor [(ngModel)]="coat.color"
              [resultFormatter]="productFormatter" [inputFormatter]="productInputFormatter"
              [ngbTypeahead]="productColorSearch" [editable]="false" />                           
</mat-form-field>
```

This is the response I get from API

```
[
  { 
     "color": "ALUMINIUM"
  }
]
```

This is the Typescript File

```
  productColorSearch = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
  return text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(750),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((searchText) => searchText.length < 3 ? [] : 
  this.facadeService.getProductColorsOnSearch(searchText))
  );
}

productFormatter = (result: any) => result.color;
productInputFormatter = (result: any) => result.color;
```

Now when I type first three letters I am supposed to get only one record in the drop-down that is "**ALU**MINIUM"
instead, I am getting all the records including **ALU**MINIUM + other colors below this.

Any help in this appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that's the response from api? So the typeahead is guessing your database content?

Comment: Your Angular application can't possibly display all these results out of nowhere. If it displays them, it means it got them, from your server. So it means your server doesn't return what you claim it does. Check your browser dev tools, in the control panel. Look at the request you send, and the response you receive.

Comment: @JBNizet checked in swagger, this is the response I get from Server.

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything wrong in the syntax of "productColorSearch "

Comment: Swagger is irrelevant. Look at the request you're **really** sending from your application, and at the response you're **really** getting. Your browser dev tools will tell you that. Not swagger.

Comment: @JBNizet yes you are right, there is something wrong with my service call, response from server is returning all records. Need to fix this first.

Comment: @EliasSoares Yes response is from server

Comment: Start by checking that you're sending the correct request. Are you really sending he search parameter?

Comment: @JBNizet This is Fixed, thanks for the help. I was sending wrong API request.